# How to track uniques in an Apache2 Access Log

Tags: apache, wordpress, apache2

**Background:**
I'm running a podcast and I'm interested in gathering statistics on the number of times an mp3 is downloaded.  The files actually reside over on Amazon S3, I simply do a 301 from a path on my server just so I'm able to catch the request in my logs.  The podcast RSS feed is managed by Wordpress.

**Problem**:
Using [IP + mp3 requested] isn't good enough to determine uniqueness. What if there are several people downloading behind a NAT?

**Question 1**:
Wordpress doesn't seem to store a cookie when one goes to the feed URL. What would I do to store a unique cookie for the user?

**Question 2**:
Is there a way - using Apache access logs only - I could log the person's cookie?  I'm pretty sure iTunes & NetNewsReader support cookies (they use Safari).  I'm not sure about <insert RSS reader of choice>,  which might not, for them IP address may be all I have to go on.

Comment: I think that you will be unable to track several people behind a NAT if they do download your podcast. Also apache access log will tell you only the referrer page, ip, browser and time. If you need such precise statistics I would think, and it's just an idea that popped in my head, to use javascript and if someone clicks on a podcast, save it (through ajax request) as a download attempt. If the user is logged in, then you could determine users and uniqueness for IPs and NAT.

Comment: The problem becomes that of people using iTunes and other podcast readers where the user isn't necessarily "clicking to download".  It's too bad, I really do want to get a good gauge on # of actual listeners

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to the end of the url where you 301 redirect and make your link yourserver.com/podcastxyz?userid=someguid.

Now if you have a way of identifying the unique user before you 301 redirect you could add the same guid at the end for the same user.

If you are not familiar with how you could identify uniques you could do it by adding a cookie with the guid with a long expiry date. Whenever you load the page where the 301 redirect takes place check for the presence of the cookie and add the guid value stored in the cookie.

Tracking unique downloads from people who do not visit your website with a browser is impossible.